# PHP implode adding extra field for no reason

Tags: php, implode

For some reason, in PHP, the `implode` function is returning an extra field from `$tmpTblRow` at the end of it's returned string and causes a MySQL error.

MySQL statement is generated from:

```
$sqll = sprintf(
    "INSERT INTO $sqlToTbl (%s) VALUES ('%s')", 
    $sqlToCols, 
    implode("','", array_values($tmpTblRow))
);
```

$tmpTblRow is the assocative array:

```
[lineItem] => null
[partID] => 1
[partNumber] => tr2-mod2-0001
[serialNumber] => 
[partDescription] => mob176wertyu
[quantity] => 10
[price] => 500
[warranty] => 
[dateRequired] => 2055-11-11
[note] => 
[discount] => 
[isProcessed] => 1
[parameter] => 
[isPrivate] => 
[processedByUserID] => 1
[processedDate] => 2013-02-04
[extPrice] => 0
[parentID] => 36
[isToAct] => 1
[userID] => 0
[type] => 
[dateGenerated] => 2013-02-04 10:53:12
[unitType] =>
```

$sqll VALUE RETURNS:

```
INSERT INTO tblOrdersItems 
    ( lineItem, partID , partNumber , serialNumber, partDescription , quantity, 
      price , warranty  , dateRequired , note , discount, isProcessed, parameter,
      isPrivate, processedByUserID, processedDate, extPrice, parentID, isToAct, 
      userID, type, dateGenerated, unitType) 
VALUES 
    ( 'null', '1', 'tr2-mod2-0001', '', 'mob176wertyu', '10', '500', '', 
      '2055-11-11', '', '', '1', '', '', '1', '2013-02-04', '0', '36', '1', '0', 
      '', '2013-02-04 10:53:12', '', '1' )
```

The return error is: "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1"

Notice the extra `1` at the end of the string `$sqll`.  Can anyone explain why and how to fix this?

edit... var_dump  for $tmpTblRow returns:

```
array(23) {
  ["lineItem"]=>
  string(4) "null"
  ["partID"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["partNumber"]=>
  string(13) "tr2-mod2-0001"
  ["serialNumber"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["partDescription"]=>
  string(12) "mob176wertyu"
  ["quantity"]=>
  string(2) "10"
  ["price"]=>
  string(3) "500"
  ["warranty"]=>
  NULL
  ["dateRequired"]=>
  string(10) "2055-11-11"
  ["note"]=>
  NULL
  ["discount"]=>
  NULL
  ["isProcessed"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["parameter"]=>
  NULL
  ["isPrivate"]=>
  NULL
  ["processedByUserID"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["processedDate"]=>
  string(10) "2013-02-04"
  ["extPrice"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["parentID"]=>
  string(2) "36"
  ["isToAct"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["userID"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["type"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["dateGenerated"]=>
  string(19) "2013-02-04 10:53:12"
  ["unitType"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

... and the full code is  this:

```
$q = "SELECT $sqlFromCols FROM $sqlFromTbl $sqlFromWhere";
$result1 = $conn->query(stripslashes($q)) ;
    if (!$result1) die($conn->error.">>none<< 1");

    echo $q."||";


echo "<br/>start>";
while($tmpTblRow = $result1->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC) )
{


     var_dump ($tmpTblRow);
     echo "<br/>end|";
     echo "<br/>";
    $tmpTblRow[$sqlFromIDcol] = $newID;

    $sqll = sprintf("INSERT INTO $sqlToTbl (%s) VALUES ('%s')", $sqlFromCols, implode("','",array_values($tmpTblRow)));


    echo $sqll."||";

     $result = $conn->query(stripslashes($sqll)) ;
    if (!$result) die($conn->error.">>none<< while");


    $q = "UPDATE $sqlToTbl SET $change WHERE $sqlToIDcol = $newID";
        $q = stripslashes($q);

    $result = $conn->query(stripslashes($q)) ;
    if (!$result) die($conn->error.">>none<< update");

        //mysql_query($q);
        //echo $q."||<br>";



    $newID = $newID+1;


}
```

Comment: scan the array first to make sure all the required values are there with acceptable values

Comment: [lineItem] => null [partID] => 1 [partNumber] => tr2-mod2-0001 [serialNumber] => [partDescription] => mob176wertyu [quantity] => 10 [price] => 500 [warranty] => [dateRequired] => 2055-11-11 [note] => [discount] => [isProcessed] => 1 [parameter] => [isPrivate] => [processedByUserID] => 1 [processedDate] => 2013-02-04 [extPrice] => 0 [parentID] => 36 [isToAct] => 1 [userID] => 0 [type] => [dateGenerated] => 2013-02-04 10:53:12 [unitType] =>  ... yehp, all there, -1

Comment: @user2040763 why did you re-write all the same values from above in a comment? Was there a purpose to that madness?

Comment: yes, because i already showed that to be case.. can anyone actually answer the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I let this code run:

```
$tmpTblRow = array(
    'lineItem' => null,
    'partID' => 1,
    'partNumber' => 'tr2-mod2-0001',
    'serialNumber' => '',
    'partDescription' => 'mob176wertyu',
    'quantity' => 10,
    'price' => 500,
    'warranty' => '',
    'dateRequired' => '2055-11-11',
    'note' => '',
    'discount' => '',
    'isProcessed' => 1,
    'parameter' => '',
    'isPrivate' => '',
    'processedByUserID' => 1,
    'processedDate' => '2013-02-04',
    'extPrice' => 0,
    'parentID' => 36,
    'isToAct' => 1,
    'userID' => 0,
    'type' => '',
    'dateGenerated' => '2013-02-04 10:53:12',
    'unitType' => '',
);

$sqlToCols = "col, col, col";

$sqll = sprintf(
    "INSERT INTO $sqlToTbl (%s) VALUES ('%s')",
    $sqlToCols,
    implode("','", array_values($tmpTblRow))
);

var_dump($sqll);
```

I get the result:

```
string(183) "INSERT INTO  (col, col, col) VALUES ('','1','tr2-mod2-0001','','mob176wertyu','10','500','','2055-11-11','','','1','','','1','2013-02-04','0','36','1','0','','2013-02-04 10:53:12','')"
```

As you can see, there is no 1 at the end. This can only mean one thing: You did not dump the right array when debugging.

Comment: thank you Sven and others for helping with my formatting of question.  I hope someone can figure this out though, it really has me stumped

Comment: $tmpTblRow = $result1->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC) is the dump....$sqll = sprintf("INSERT INTO $sqlToTbl (%s) VALUES ('%s')", $sqlToCols, implode("','",array_values($tmpTblRow))); is the string. Its IS the same $tmpTblRow

Comment: This cannot be. `var_dump($tmpTblRow)` is a dump. What is it's output?

Comment: print_r ($tmpTblRow); ... was the debug statement used, not litterally var_dump

Comment: And the result from another run? The code is OK, your data is wrong, e.g. it does contain more values than you expect. You are the only one that can check this, nobody on Stackoverflow can help you with this step.

Comment: ok, now i just updated my question with the vardump values btw.  I have checked many times.  all im giving is a litteral cut and paste of my code and the results

Comment: its something with that implode statement, its the only thing not giving me the right reponse. so weird

Comment: No, the implode works correctly, as does the array_values(). It must be somewhere else in your code. Can you try and copy/paste my code example into a single file on your machine and run it? Try to add things that are in your code from there.

Comment: ok I added the full code btw

Comment: Ok, here we are: `$tmpTblRow[$sqlFromIDcol] = $newID;` You are adding an array field after your dump! Q.E.D.

Comment: By the way: If you want to copy data inside the database, there is a `INSERT ... SELECT` statement that does just this, and it is even faster. And while we are at it: Why the hell do you `stripslashes()` your SQL strings? I suspect you are attackable by SQL injection, because this simply makes no sense.

Comment: stripslashes() was copied and pasted from other code I made and I did not care to mine it out... Noted about the INSERT ... SELECT, Thank you again